# Category slug + post slug Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a blog route and I'd like to show article with a category_slug.

```
Route::get('/blog/{category_slug}/{slug}', [App\Http\Controllers\BlogController::class, 'index'])
       ->where('category_slug', '[\-_A-Za-z]+')
       ->where('slug', '[\-_A-Za-z]+');


public function categories_blog()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(CategoriesBlog::class, 'category_id');
}

public function blogs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Blog::class);
}
```

with this eloquent relations works fine:

example: [www.mysite.com/blog/first_article](http://www.mysite.com/blog/first_article)

```
public function index($category_slug, $slug)
{

$blogs = Blog::with('categories_blog')
               ->where('slug', '=', $slug)
               ->first();

}
```

with this eloquent relations doesn't work:

example: [www.mysite.com/blog/accessories/first_article](http://www.mysite.com/blog/accessories/first_article)

```
public function index($category_slug, $slug)
{

$blogs = Blog::with('categories_blog')
             ->where('category_slug', '=', $category_slug)
             ->where('slug', '=', $slug)
             ->first();  

}
```

Doesn't recognize relationship with 'categories blogs':

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_slug' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `blogs` where `category_slug` = accessories `slug` = first_article limit 1)
```

How I can fix it or is there is a best way for get this?
thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use whereHas

```
$blogs = Blog::with('categories_blog')->whereHas('categories_blog',function ($query)use($category_slug){
           $query ->where('category_slug', $category_slug);
       })
          ->where('slug',$slug)
          ->first();
```